# Call webpage in the background with PHP

Tags: php, cgi, html

I am trying to write a simple PHP script to retrieve some images from a server - there are four in total. However, everytime I get a new image I need to call a webpage before, i.e `http://example.com/Set.cgi?Image=1`

I have no control over what is on the server - I just need to work around it. I have read that it is possible using cURL but I'm not sure if my shared host (JustHost) supports it...

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it works?  If you are shared hosting, it may be blocked, but it could be open still.  Write a script and give it a try.

Comment: `everytime I get a new image I need to call a webpage before`. Can you clarify this?

Comment: If the cURL extension is missing you can try with fopen or file_get_contents. Those can be disabled too but you can try it.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon When I say 'I need to', I don't mean that it wont work if I don't. I need to run the URL that I stated (or something like it) in order for the next image to be saved! Also, I can confirm that cURL is in fact enabled!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) in the following manner. The following code is from an example on that page.

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/Set.cgi?Image=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

1)even you can use http://php.net/dom to get the web page and fetch it using DOM. but still it needs to enable "allow_url_fopen" directive open.

2) you can use `var_dump(ini_get("allow_url_fopen"))` to see it is enable or not. you may have permission to put directory based php.ini on your shared host. in this case you can make it enable.

3) you can check using `phpinfo()` that curl is enabled or not

4) you can use sockets ti simulate curl using [fsockopen](http://php.net/fsockopen).

Comment: Thanks for how to do that. I've just checked `phpinfo()` and cURL is actually enabled!